# How do you sum incrementally down a column until a value is reached, then start the sum counter over from the last position using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, sum

So I am trying to cumulatively sum down a column until a value is reached, then in the column adjacent to the column with the values, add a text of some sort that indicates where one sum ended and a new one began. Next, I want to restart the sum from where I left off with a value of 0 and keep doing this until there are no more values to sum.

This is what I have but it does not seem to be working properly (It prematurely begins to increment to the next step even though the sum of "~3815" has not been reached:

```
Private Sub NumberOfTrucks_Click()
  Dim j As Integer
  Dim i As Integer

  '~~> j stands for number of summed segments
    j = 1
    dbSumTotal = 0
    lastrow = Range("AU" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To lastrow Step 1
   '~~> in column AU are the numbers for the sum
        dbSumTotal = dbSumTotal + Cells(i, "AU").Value
   '~~> write value to cell and reset sum to 0
        If dbSumTotal >= 3815.9999999 Then
           dbSumTotal = 0
  '~~> for next sum raise the segment number
           j = j + 1
        End If
        Cells(i, "AX") = j
    Next i
    MsgBox ("Completed")
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want this to go 1,2,3,4,5 etc in column AX until the sum reaches 3815 then go back to 1 and start again? If so, set `j = 0` instead of 1, add a `j = 0` underneath `dbsumtotal = 0` line, then add an `Else` above the `j = j + 1` line.

Comment: You don't seem to write `dbSumTotal` anywhere.Should AX be the sum or the line count?

Comment: Nevermind I see what the issue is. Gimme a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Incremental Sum

**A Quick Fix**

```
Private Sub NumberOfTrucks_Click()
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dbSumTotal As Double
    
    LastRow = Range("AU" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    '~~> j stands for number of summed segments
    j = 1
    
    For i = 3 To LastRow
    '~~> in column AU are the numbers for the sum
        dbSumTotal = dbSumTotal + Cells(i, "AU").Value
        Cells(i, "AX") = j
        ' To make it more obvious, uncomment the following line.
        'Cells(i, "AY") = dbSumTotal
    '~~> write value to cell and reset sum to 0
        If dbSumTotal >= 3815.9999999 Then
        ' 3815.9999999 might be a left over when you were using '>',
        ' so I think the previous line should be:
        'If dbSumTotal >= 3816 Then
            dbSumTotal = 0
    '~~> for next sum raise the segment number
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    MsgBox ("Completed")

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey VBasic2008, This was a big help to simply show me that the calculation on dbSumTotal is not working as expected; that is, it is cumulatively summing all the way to the end of data instead of restarting once 3815, is reached. So, i think my issue is in dbSumTotal and i need to see how to fix that statement of the script. Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain what is wrong with this solution?

Comment: VBasic2008. I just realized my mistake. It was not in your addition at all. Rather, it was in my application. I had an issue with my data and fixed that issue. It is now working. Your addition(s) helped me get there. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here we are.

You're issue was when you got to the row that was over 3815, you added to `j`, then wrote to column `AX`. Now instead, we write to `AX` then add to `j`.

```
Private Sub NumberOfTrucks_Click()
  Dim j As Integer
  Dim i As Integer

  '~~> j stands for number of summed segments
    j = 1
    dbSumTotal = 0
    lastrow = Range("AU" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To lastrow Step 1
   '~~> in column AU are the numbers for the sum
        dbSumTotal = dbSumTotal + Cells(i, "AU").Value
   '~~> write value to cell and reset sum to 0
        If dbSumTotal >= 3815.9999999 Then
           dbSumTotal = 0
           Cells(i, "AX") = j
           j = j + 1
        Else
  '~~> for next sum raise the segment number
           Cells(i, "AX") = j
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox ("Completed")
End Sub
```